# Use Resource Dictionary Styles in my class library project without merging dictionaries

Tags: wpf, resources, resourcedictionary

I am creating a class library project that will contain WPF user controls. **My Requirement is that all controls have the same style**. My project looks like:

[image]

Things I have done in order to solve this problem:

1. Added all references needed by a WPF application *System.Xaml, WindowsBase, etc..* so that I can have wpf controls in my class library project.
2. In *AssemblyInfo.cs* I have added:

   `[assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]`
3. Added *ResourceDictionary1.xaml* To the project adding the style.

   `<ResourceDictionary
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush1" Color="#FF19199E"/>

    </ResourceDictionary>`
4. Now if I want to use a style on my *UserControl1.xaml* I do:

   ```
   <UserControl.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary1.xaml" />
           </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       </ResourceDictionary>

   </UserControl.Resources>

   <Grid >
       <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource Brush1}"  />
   </Grid>
   ```

**I know it works great but here is the catch.** Every time I create a new userControl I will have to merge the dictionary. On a regular WPF application I could just merge the dictionary once on App.xaml and I will be able to use that dictionary on my entire application. **How can I avoid having to merge the dictionary every time I create a new userControl?** If I plan on addying a new resource dictionary I will have to go to all userControls and merge another dictionary. **Perhaps I wrote the question title incorrectly and my question should have been how can I add a App.xaml file to a class library project**

Comment: You could try putting the common resources for your assembly in a `Themes\Generic.xaml` resource dictionary (with Build Action set to "Page").  That's where WPF expects a control library's default, theme-independent styles to go, so those resources should be automatically loaded into your application.  Typically, that file doesn't actually declare any resources, but uses `MergedDictionaries` to pull in resources from other files.

Comment: Why don't you have a wpf project in your solution and add your class library as a reference there. From there you can make call to the user-control or plain window as your start-up screen

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46258276/417939. In short, the class library can use the application resources defined in the startup application at both design time and runtime.

Answer (score -1):

You should replace the source value `ResourceDictionary1.xaml` like the follow:

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/ControlsDLL;component/ResourceDictionary1.xaml">
```

or just simple as following:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ControlsDLL;component/ResourceDictionary1.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ControlsDLL;component/ResourceDictionary1.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>